# FCM does not open necessary Activity when app is closed

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Sorry for my English. Before I use **GCM** for push notifications and I have one problem when my app is closed and I click on notification opened only `mainactivity.class` not the one that I put for when click notification is open necessary activity. The problem was that I extends in `GcmListenerService` like [documentation](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java#L43-L69) I decided it when extends `IntentService` and it was working. When my app is closed and I click on notification opened necessary activity.

Then I want got to **FCM** and i have same problem when i extends on `GcmListenerService` but now i extends on `FirebaseMessagingService` and now like before i cant open necessare activity when app is closed.

Before(when all work file) in `manifest` i have (GcmMessageHandler - my push class)

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.nga.plancentral" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="push.GcmMessageHandler"  
           android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Now in manifest i have

```
 <service
        android:name="push.FBMnotification">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Please add the request you are using to send the message to the device.

Comment: Do post code snippets on how you are handling the notifications (before/GCM and after/FCM).